# How can I find contours in specific area of image using opencv and C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new to opencv. I am trying to detect vehicles in a specific are of the image like x=0 to 139 and y=0 to 300 of a image with size (300, 400) approximately.

So what condition should I use to detect it in specific area and to count the vehicle once it pass enters into the frame?

```
enter code herevoid processVideo(char* videoFilename) {
//create the capture object
`VideoCapture capture(videoFilename);
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    //error in opening the video input
    cerr << "Unable to open video file: " << videoFilename << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//read input data. ESC or 'q' for quitting
while( (char)keyboard != 'q' && (char)keyboard != 27 ){
    //read the current frame
    if(!capture.read(frame)) {
        cerr << "Unable to read next frame." << endl;
        cerr << "Exiting..." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //update the background model
    pMOG2->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2);
    Mat im_th, src_gray;
    cvtColor( frame, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    medianBlur( fgMaskMOG2, fgMaskMOG2, 15 );
    threshold( fgMaskMOG2, im_th,230 , 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        Mat im_floodfill = im_th.clone();
       floodFill(im_floodfill, cv::Point(0,0), Scalar(255));

       Mat im_floodfill_inv;
       bitwise_not(im_floodfill, im_floodfill_inv);
       fgMaskMOG2= im_floodfill_inv;

       dilate(fgMaskMOG2, fgMaskMOG2,Mat ());
       erode(fgMaskMOG2, fgMaskMOG2,Mat ());
       medianBlur( fgMaskMOG2, fgMaskMOG2, 15 );
       //adaptiveThreshold(fgMaskMOG2,fgMaskMOG2 ,255,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,THRESH_BINARY,11,2);

               rectangle(frame, cv::Point(10, 2), cv::Point(100,20),
                         cv::Scalar(255,0,255), -1);

               stringstream ss;
               ss << capture.get(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
               string frameNumberString = ss.str();
               putText(frame, frameNumberString.c_str(), cv::Point(15, 15),
                       FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5 , cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
               //show the current frame and the fg masks
               imshow("Frame", frame);
               imshow("FG Mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);

              vector<vector<Point> > contours;
               vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

               findContours( fgMaskMOG2, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0) );

               Mat drawing = frame;

                   Rect bounding_rect;

                   vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
                   vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );


                   Scalar color( 255,0,0);  // color of the contour in the
                   //Draw the contour and rectangle


                   for( int i = 0; i < s; i++ )
                       { //approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
                       approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
                         boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );

                       }
);

                   for( int i = 0; i< s; i++ )
                       {
                       drawContours( frame, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
                       rectangle( frame, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
                       }
                   imshow( "Display window", frame);
               }

               keyboard = waitKey(39);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change :

```
findContours( fgMaskMOG2, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, 
Point(0,0) );
```

To:

```
findContours( fgMaskMOG2(cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)), contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, 
Point(0,0) );
```

Where `cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)` represents the ROI

Comment: I'd mention also that you can call `findContours( fgMaskMOG2(cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)), ...` with offset `Point(x,y)` to have contours with original image coordinates.

Comment: @Miki yes you are right with Point (x, y), it worked correctly

Comment: how to find x and y